# Phonegap with a fixed internal browser?

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, webview, compilation

I have been evaluating Phonegap for development of games. I like that you can implement full-screen, but that Phonegap uses the native and very buggy web view for Android 4.3 and below is very discouraging. It's simply extremely slow and now I have to worry about both the buggy web view and still worry about the differences between different web views (eg: iOS vs. android).

I would love someone to provide a link or written tutorial on how I can go about inserting a fixed/built-in browser into a Phonegap build -- for example, the latest Chrome version. Chrome is still slow, but much better than native web view. I would also like to lock down the browser version. This would really help development.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can do this tbh.

Have you asked at the Phonegap support pages?

If you use a framework for you game development it'll erase many of the cross-browser issues you'll encounter.

As someone who has used Phonegap Build I'm not sure I'd use PG for game development. Have you looked at Unity? You can script with js in it.

Comment: I did post in the support area here: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/internal_browser_is_there_a_way_to_add_one ... I did some more research after I made this post and I got a few suggestions, none of them perfect. The most promising one is this: https://github.com/thedracle/cordova-android-chromeview, but it's abandoned. I haven't looked at Unity yet... not in a few years, at least. I will, though. Thanks!